# Terminal Command for Purge of Nvidia and Install New Package

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, purge

What is the Terminal command to purge all current Nvidia drivers and install Nvidia binary driver - version 331.104?

Comment: Do you want to install the Linux Display Driver NVIDIA Certified Version 331.1040 from the official [NVIDIA Driver Downloads](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) website? Before you install the graphics driver please run `ubuntu-drivers devices` from the terminal in order to find out which NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver is recommended for your system.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... I checked and it listed three drivers... nvidia-340, nvidia-331, and nouveau... I followed the below instructions to install nouveau: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely

Comment: Seems to be working

Comment: You have nvidia-340 listed in the output of `ubuntu-drivers devices` means that a graphics driver that you downloaded from the official NVIDIA website was already installed. If you have uninstalled it and run the command `ubuntu-drivers devices` again it will tell you the recommended graphics driver from only the Ubuntu repositories, which is usually a better graphics driver than a graphics driver which you download from the official NVIDIA website.

Comment: I purged all Nvidia drivers by running command sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*  Then ran the command you recommended and tried all three drivers. Nvidia-340 works the best, but video playback still has some unavoidable glitchiness to it.

Comment: You might be able to get rid of some of the glitchiness by installing Chromium Web Browser and Pepper Flash Player and then updating Pepper Flash Player to the latest version, which is version 15 instead of version 11 for Adobe Flash Player, it's a lot less glitchy. [How to update Pepper Flash Player to the latest version](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482900/flash-player-in-firefox-is-unstable-in-14-04/484388#484388).

Comment: The glitchiness happens using VLC and playing downloaded mp4 files.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what nvidia driver is installed, run the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

To purge the driver (nvidia-340 for example) run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-340
```

To install version 331.89 run the following command or skip this command and install the ppa for version 331.104:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

---

Save any unsaved files before you begin.

To install version 331.104 go to this website http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/331.104/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.104.run&lang=us&type=geforcem

Click to agree to the terms and conditions and download the file to your home folder (~/). Then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> login with your username and password and execute the following command:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

If you use GDM, type this command instead:

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

Then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms gcc build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-source
sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.104.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.104.run
```

Follow the instructions and reboot when you are done.