# Ubuntu doesn't boot after i accidentally restarted while changing settings

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia-settings

I bought Asus Zen screen and it was working fine then for one Python project I messed up the Nvidia and changed the graphic card from setting-> update software and changed to something like "x blah blah" Sorry for my language I do remember what I did it was long ago then I left my pc when I returned after hour the same thing loading and I couldn't access tried to restart after that when it boots show me one "-" and the screen is blank
[image: my pc after booting]

Comment: You might mention what version of Ubuntu. Maybe edit your question... Ubuntu (version) does not boot after Nvidia settings accident. If you know what Nvidia driver version, that would help. The left shift key or some times it is escape key might get you into grub and you can select a command prompt or recovery mode, and be able to purge the Nvidia driver and reinstall it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/546609/terminal-command-for-purge-of-nvidia-and-install-new-package https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation

Comment: Some punctuation would really help this post's readability.

Comment: sounds like the video driver is crashing when the grpahical environment tries to start.  Probably can get to a text login with alt-F3 or some other function key.  Then reinstall the correct graphics driver from the command line would fix it.